# Space to the right in mobile and desktop view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, mdbootstrap

I'm making an instagram story style template. What I have done so far is to define a fluid container and inside it, add three columns with content such as progress bars, a logo, etc.

Everything works fine, except that for some reason, there is a space on the right side of the screen at any resolution. I have tried several techniques, such as adding a width of 100% to the container, removing the padding from the body, with no results.

This is the body and the main components of my template:

```html
<body style="background-color: #000; overflow-x: hidden;">
  <!-- Container with background color and 100% height -->
  <div class="container-fluid" style="height: 100vh; padding:0px;">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="row">
        <!-- Hide on small screens -->
        <div class="col-lg-4 d-none d-lg-block" style="background-color: #F4F4F4;">

        </div>
        <!-- Hide on small screens -->

        <!-- Main content -->
        <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color: #fff; height: 100vh;">
           ...
        </div>
        <!-- Main content -->

        <!-- Hide on small screens -->
        <div class="col-lg-4 d-none d-lg-block" style="background-color: #F4F4F4;">

        </div>
        <!-- Hide on small screens -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

This is the resulting space. I've colored black so it's more visible.
[image]

[Here is a link to my snippet](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/standard/javier_santiago_valenzuela_cordero/2891735?view=standard), I really need help, I don't know what's going on. Thank you very much in advance. I know that the style should not be inline, it is like this while I am building the site.

Comment: There is padding and margin for class row that you need to review.

Comment: Thank you Gerard, worked adding padding and margin 0.

Answer (score 0):

Solved adding `margin: 0px; padding: 0px;` to the row class.